# File extension ~ meaning

Tags: php

I don't know is here is a proper place to ask that question, but I'm noticed that all files I created have their duplicates with `~` ending. For example:

```
index.php
index.php~
home.php
home.php~
show.php
show.php~
```

and so on.

What does this mean? Can I delete it?

Comment: That used to be a Unix convention for backup files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files ending with a ~ character are usually backups, under linux systems. It is safe to delete them, after you made sure that you no longer need it/them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not home in php, but doesn't that mean it's a temporary/back-up file, meaning your original file isn't saved?

Answer (score 0):

Is your php-editor currently running? (Or maybe stopped it abnormally?)

In this case these backup-files are in use by your editor - or they wasn't deleted correctly, after your editor was closed.

Comment: No, it's not running.  Actually usualy they are hidden, but I just noticed them when I tried to upload files in server with FileZilla. And questioned whether to move them to the server or not.